# Signal R Self Hosting windows service is not accessible through signal R Client c sharp

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, self-hosting

I have created a windows service, and tried to host a signal r in it. 
It is hosted successfully in windows service, but when trying to call it from signal r client it is giving me exception unable to connect to remote server.
The same code when i tried to access from console app it is working correctly. Although i tried to access it via ip and localhost too.
[Windows service code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjgC5.png)

[client code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcJNG.png)

Without hosting it in windows service, i write same code in console app and tried to access it from the same client it is working. I have also Off my firewall and created the inbound rule for this port. Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: Show code as text, please!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is configured to listen on IP while your client is trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: It is listening on 5000 , 1122 port is commented.